# MonoTouch. Removing a particular UIImage SubView from ViewController

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xamarin.ios, subview

How to find and remove a `UIImageView` from the collection of `ParentViewController.View.Subviews` very quick?

Right now I'm comparing the Image.Size but it works slow and sometimes flickers. Comparing Image objects fails.

upd... the reason of the flickering turned out to be some other stuff I messed up. I fixed that. Still, comparing by `Image.Size` doesn't seem like a very good idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this :

Add a unique tag property (int) to your `UIImageView`:

`myImageView.Tag = 100;`

Then, with this tag, you can remove it from the superview:

`ParentViewController.View.ViewWithTag(100).RemoveFromSuperview();`